I get This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play error only on Android TV platform
I have an app that published at Google Play Store. I developed it with Flutter and in_app_purchase package.
This app has a subscription and subscription is working perfectly at touch based android devices such as phones and tablets. I use the same app bundle to publish it at Android TV platform and when I try to subscribe it with Android TV, I get this error message:
This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play

I searched and I found similar questions about same error message but none of them for Android TV platform. All other questions and answers are for touch based devices such as phone and tablets. But my app is working fine at phone and tablets.
Are there any specific steps required for Android TV platform for subscription setup?
Thanks

It happen with me when I make Apk file ,but once I delete the Apk and reinstall it .error goes away
